# Continuous map from closed set to relatively compact set

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $V$ be a complete normed space and let $f: X\to f(X)\subset X\subset V$ be continuous.

Can you find an example of a pair $f,X$ such that $X$ is closed in $V$ and $f(X)$ is relatively compact but not compact, despite $f$ being continuous?

Comment: Do you have an exemple of a relatively compact but non compact subspace ?

Comment: An open ball in $X=[0,1]$, take the ball $\{ x \in X | \lvert x - 0.5 \rvert < 0.25\}$ its closure is compact.

Comment: What do you mean by $X$ being "closed"? Closed in what?

Comment: @MartinGeller, ok now can you build a function with image your relative compact space ?

Comment: $f: B \to B$ given by  $f(x) = x$ where $B = \{x \in X|| x-0.5 \mid<0.25\}$

Comment: @tomasz, just fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X = \{(x,0): x \in \Bbb R\}$, $V=\Bbb R^2$: $f$ defined by $f(x,0)=(\arctan(x),0)$.

$f$ is continuous, $X$ is closed in $V$, $f[X] \subset X \subset V$ and $f[X]$ is relatively compact.